# Hosts file in Android Lollipop not being used?

Tags: android

I have a suspicion that the hosts file in Android Lollipop is not being used (located at /etc/hosts).  After rooting my Nexus 4, I can modify the hosts file to effectively block ad and malware sites, eg

```
0.0.0.0 adcomplete.com
```

I use this method on every device I own, and it's worked like a charm on all previous version of Android.

Is it possible that Lollipop no longer uses the hosts file?

Is it possible that I have somehow made an error to the hosts file?  Would there be any logs of incorrectly configured hosts files?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Additionally to George's answer about line endings, there has to be a line ending (LF) after the last entry in the file. That's what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem.  Android Lollipop IS using the hosts file correctly. The problem was the contents of the host file, which I got from:

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt

Note that it reads :

`This *must* be the first line: 127.0.0.1     localhost`

Which I hadn't made sure in my hosts file on my android device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My issue turned out to be Windows line endings in the file that I appended to `hosts`. Removing the `^M`s with `vi` worked.